# Name or Service not Known when calling service via spring boot in Openshift Container Platform (a cloud-based Kubernetes container platform)

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, kubernetes, openshift

I have an application which consists of a backend (spring boot) and a search engine (elasticsearch). After I deployed it into OCP, Initially I tested the connection between the two using the command "curl" to elasticsearch service `(https://service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local:9200)` from backend pod and it worked. Here's the picture:
[image]

However, when I try to access elasticsearch from within the deployed backend application, an error message appears as below:
[image]

And here are my configuration in Spring Boot to connect with Elasticsearch that I did:

```
package com.siolbca.config;

import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.RestClients;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.siolbca.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.siolbca.services")
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration 
            = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("https://elasticsearch-siol-es-http.siolbca-dev.svc.cluster.local:9200")
                .usingSsl()
                .withBasicAuth("elastic","G0D1g6TurJ79pcxr1065pU0U")
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
    }

}
```

Some of the things I have done are:

1. Use the elasticsearch service IP address directly in the backend configuration

> https://elasticsearch-service-ipaddress:9200

2. Expose a route from elasticsearch service and put it in the backend configuration

> https://elasticsearch-route:443

3. Change the service url into

> https://service-name.namespace.svc:9200

Does anyone know why my backend app can't communicate with the elasticsearch service even though the two pods are able to connect? Any answer would be very helpful. Thank you.

---

**EDIT**

Here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.siolbca</groupId>
    <artifactId>siolbca</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>siolbca</name>
    <description>Backend project for SIOLBCA</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I can not understand your question properly ,If you have any specific application properties and dependencies in your pom.xml please add them also

Comment: `Name or service not known` clearly indicates a problem with name resolution. Are you sure your pod is using in-cluster DNS for name resolution? Can you share your pod spec?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've changed my question by adding the pom.xml configuration. In short, my question is "Unable to call Elasticsearch Service from Spring Boot when Deployed to Openshift even though the pods when tested were connected to each other." @MikaelAmidi

Comment: Actually I used the deployment & pod from the Elasticsearch Operator available at Openshift. I didn't make any configuration changes on the elasticsearch side. What is ‘in-cluster DNS ‘and on which pods can I change it? @whites11

Comment: I followed this website when deploy the Elasticsearch (ECK) operator on Openshift. [https://www.openshift.com/blog/run-elastic-cloud-on-kubernetes-on-red-hat-openshift @whites11

Comment: Answer by jhyot is a possible explanation. Anyway, every kubernetes cluster has an internal DNS server (usually coreDNS) that resolves internal names. Internal names are those related to services deployed in the cluster. By default all pods use that DNS server to resolve all DNS names, but its possible to override the default and use an external DNS instead. That's why I asked you to share details about how your spring boot up is running.

Comment: Answer by jhyot successfully resolved the error that I found (Name or Service Not Known). Actually, I found new error which is "sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". I'll try to troubleshoot that new error. Thanks for your kindness @whites11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the elasticsearch builder `.connectedTo` method requires the format `host:port`,  i.e. without the protocol.
So try:

```
.connectedTo("elasticsearch-siol-es-http.siolbca-dev.svc.cluster.local:9200")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually it worked and I'm no longer found "Name or Service Not Known" error. But I found another error which is "sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". I'll try to find what cause that problem. Thank you